# How to fix a Jenkins error?

Tags: ros, jenkins, build, github, release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

the binary builds of my package in Jenkins failed with a dependency error.
I fixed the error in my CMakeLists.txt file and updated the Github repo accordingly.
However the last two builds still failed with the same error.
I was assuming that Jenkins downloads the files from Github every time it tries to build?

Do I have to do anything else in order to make Jenkins build from the updated repo?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/216407/how-to-fix-a-jenkins-error?/) by [DKS](https://answers.ros.org/users/21308/dks/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2015-08-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Do I have to do anything else in order to make Jenkins build from the updated repo?

yes: you have to do a Bloom release of the fixed version. Jenkins (the buildfarm really) will only build *released* versions of your packages. It does not make a clone of `HEAD`.

PS:

> the binary builds of my package in Jenkins failed with a dependency error. I fixed the error in my CMakeLists.txt file and updated the Github repo accordingly.

To catch these kind of things before you push a new release, you can do a prerelease test run, see [wiki/bloom/Tutorials/PrereleaseTest](http://wiki.ros.org/bloom/Tutorials/PrereleaseTest).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-08-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1